# SQL Server Default Database when Query - master

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, sql-server-2012

I've been using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) for the last 8 years, and I keep on stumbling upon a problem. When I right click on a Table, and select SELECT TOP 2000 ROWS, the query editor opens up a new file with the query inside. This is nice and all for a quick review of the table.

The problem I have is the default database is changed from the actual database to the master database. I have sysadmin rights.

The query that gets generated by SSMS, then has the databse, schema, and table in brackets, i.e. [DB].[dbo].[TableName]

Is there a way to set the default database on the SELECT TOP 2000 ROWS command, to NOT go and set the default database to 'master' ?

The other workaround is to click on the table, and then do a 'New Query', which will keep the current database, and then I have to type in 'SELECT * FROM TableName'

[image: default database changed to master]

Comment: You could do `Script table as >> SELECT to >> New Query Editor Window` but you would have to add in the `SELECT TOP 2000` which is probably on a par with the amount of effort required to write `USE Database` and remove the database name from the select command

Comment: It would help if you didn't keep referring to this as the "default database" changing - it's a new connection, and it default to using your default database (that happens to be master) - it's not *changing* the default database, it's using it. And no, there's no way to change this behaviour.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In SSMS go to Security > Logins - choose your login, then right-click and choose Properties - at the bottom of the tab is an option called "Default Database" - this is what you want to change.

Comment: This only solves the problem if the table you want to select the top 2000 from is in the default database.

Comment: In case you don't know where `Security` is: in Object Explorer, expand the folder of the server instance with which you want to work, `Security` resides there right after `Databases`.