# In SQL Server (2012), when can I just use a table name "Foo" w/o the full qualification dbname.dbo.Foo?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Is there a setting in the management studio that would allow me, when I create a new query, to use just:

```
SELECT * FROM Foo
```

**instead of**

```
SELECT * FROM dbname.dbo.Foo
```

assuming of course there is no ambiguity?

Currently I get an error message. Thanks.

Comment: `Currently I get an error message`. And that error message says...? Why the mystery?

Comment: if you'll run `use dbname` to make `dbname` database your current database, you could run select * from Foo (if Foo created with dbo schema)

Comment: Sounds like you might need to change your [default database](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10928283/73226) if you always have to use three part names. Or just remember to select the correct database context in the drop down list.

Comment: You should never use just `SELECT * FROM Foo`. Please read these two posts about why laziness can be bad: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list.aspx https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

**SELECT YOUR DATABASE NAME HERE FROM THE DROP DOWN LIST** and then if there is any ambiguity in column names just use two part name i.e **TABLENAME.ColumnName**
WHere you open a new query window it opens it in **Master** database context, And people who has been working with sql server for years and years makes this mistake quite often of openning a query window and start executing a script in master db. so your not the only one :)

You can also use the **USE** statement i.e

```
USE DataBase_Name
GO

//your query.........
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a default schema for a User in SQL Server 2012.

**[Here is the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060.aspx)**

Note: You can't change the schema after setting it once.